# query different free share spaces by powershell, but every time got the same result

Tags: powershell, network-share

Here is my codes:

```
$map = new-Object -com wscript.Network
$map.mapNetworkDrive("v:","\\sharespace\testbuilds\test1")
$fso = new-Object -com Scripting.FileSystemObject
$do = $fso.getdrive("v")
$do.AvailableSpace
$do.TotalSize
```

I was mean to some check free share spaces. When I ran these codes at the first time I got a correct size data. BUt when I change the path on the 2nd line, it give me an error alarm:

```
 Exception calling "MapNetworkDrive" with "2" argument(s): "The local device name is already in use."
 At D:\test2fornetworkspace.ps1:5 char:21
 + $map.mapNetworkDrive <<<< ("v:","\\sharespace\testbuilds\test1")
 + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComMethodTargetInvocation
```

And then, the result came out and alway same to the first running result... Of couse different sharespace with the different free size. So this is totally wrong...

Why this happened? Please give me some help..many thanks....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is telling you V: is already mapped. You need to drop that mapping to reuse the drive letter V.

You should do this before re-mapping another drive to V:

`$map.removenetworkdrive("v:")`