# Doest Get-PSDrive can map network space?

Tags: powershell, network-share

Here are my codes, `$var.droppath` is a valid network space path, I've test it.

```
$map3 = new-PSDrive -name droppath -psprovider FileSystem -root $var.droppath
```

Then I ran

```
Get-PSDrive | ?{$_.Name -match "droppath"} | FT -AutoSize
```

and got the result:

```
Name     Used (GB) Free (GB) Provider  Root                                                                                                 CurrentLocation
----     --------- --------- --------   ----                                                                                                 ---------------
droppath                     FileSystem \\network\sharespace\test1
```

Why used space and free space are empty? Is that means get-psdrive can not mapping network space or I made some mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the Get-PSDrive tool only returns Free and Used information for providers that have that information available. Oddly enough, PS doesn't make that easy to get for the PS-Drives simply because it is really and alias that MIGHT map to something that doesn't have that info. PS-drives only survive the session so they aren't full OS level mappings. Thus you don't get OS level information like the remote space free.

The easy work-around is to use `net use` and map it to a real drive letter. Don't forget to tear it back down when you are done.

**UPDATE** I left out this link: [query different free share spaces by powershell, but every time got the same result](https://serverfault.com/questions/287815/query-different-free-share-spaces-by-powershell-but-every-time-got-the-same-resu/287906) which has some example code to do the mapping from PS and get the data you need manually.

Comment: @Mrak: Thanks a lot. So it doesn't work...I think I have to go back and met my previous solusion problem.. byt the way the link you've given is posted by me either... I have passed that stage but met some new problems here:http://serverfault.com/questions/288154/failed-to-check-share-space-via-recorded-path-form-sql-database-by-powershell

Answer (score 0):

Mark is correct, but looking at the TechNet article on Get-PSDrive [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315263.aspx), you can see that by using get-wmiobject and the win32_logicaldisk class you can get free space and total space pretty easily.